# Query using keywords in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Post model, with two attributes: title and content.

I'm trying to make a search form that will look for keywords in the title and/or the content columns.

Let's say there's this record:

```
title: Foobar bar foo
content: foobar baz foo
```

Now, if a user inputs the "bar baz" or "baz bar" keywords (order is not important), that record should be found.

What sort of query do I need to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain the user input is space separated (per keyword):

If you use Postresql this would work:

```
keywords = user_input.split(" ").map{ |val| "%#{val}%"}

Post.where("title iLIKE ANY ( array[?] )", keywords)
```

For multiple columns:

```
Post.where("title iLIKE ANY ( array[?] ) OR content iLIKE ANY ( array[?] )", keywords, keywords)
```

Comment: Is it specific to Postgres? I'm using sqlite3 in development

Comment: I think this works only on Postgres, do you use Postgres in production ? If yes I would use Postgres locally too, try to mimic production env as best as possible.

Comment: I've installed postgresql and you were right: it only works on postgres. Your query is very good, but not a complete solution. Do you know how to use two columns in the query? I want to look for matches in the title and content columns.

Comment: I've updated the answer according to your specs, please accept the answer with the green arrow on the left of the votes

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Post model with title and content attributes then you can search records like :

```
Post.where("(title ILIKE (?)) or (content ILIKE (?))","%#{params[:title_param]}%","%#{params[:content_param]}")
```

Comment: That would imply knowing in advance how many keywords the user is using. Also, does that cover the "order is not important" part? Thank you for your help